# How to include a Windows Word document in a HWND?

Tags: c, windows, mfc

I'm looking for including a Word document in a plain-C application. I tried several examples found on the WEB but they are mainly VBA or MFC oriented. Is someone has a link?

My application is made of windows (HWND or, if needed CWnd pointers). One of this window should inherit all the WORD document I want to edit (basically the commands SAVE can be outside). I can not get the correct way to show the WORD document *inside* my application.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This used to be possible in the previous century through a feature called Object Linking and Embedding.  Time has not been kind to it, and it never worked that well in the first place, you don't just embed the features of another program, you embed all of its bugs as well.  Particularly hostile to program in C btw.  This is over and done with and will never come back again.  It is like the old USSR jokes: you don't embed an Office program, it embeds you.

Answer (score 1):

You could embed it using OLE. Take a look at [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316207) for an example of how to do it.